# How can I get a persistent dirstack with unique entries in zsh?

Tags: zsh, directory, cd-command, pushd

The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/zsh#Dirstack) has this interesting bit of zsh configuration:

```sh
DIRSTACKFILE="$HOME/.cache/zsh/dirs"
if [[ -f $DIRSTACKFILE ]] && [[ $#dirstack -eq 0 ]]; then
  dirstack=( ${(f)"$(< $DIRSTACKFILE)"} )
  [[ -d $dirstack[1] ]] && cd $dirstack[1]
fi
chpwd() {
  print -l $PWD ${(u)dirstack} >$DIRSTACKFILE
}

DIRSTACKSIZE=20    

setopt autopushd pushdsilent pushdtohome

## Remove duplicate entries
setopt pushdignoredups

## This reverts the +/- operators.
setopt pushdminus
```

Even though `pushdignoredups` is set, I find duplicate entries in the output of `dirs`, sometimes even the same entry repeated thrice. The Wiki does go on to say that this doesn't work well with multiple zsh sessions, and I do have multiple terminal tabs open with zsh running, so that may be the cause of the problem.

Can I modify this function somehow to keep only unique entries? Is this a convoluted way of achieving something that zsh provides easier ways to do?

How can I have a persistent dirstack, with only unique entries?

Answer (score 1):

The simple `typeset -U dirstack` fails, as `dirstack` is doubtless too special for the usual unique limitation to apply (this `typeset` is however handy for things like the `path` array). On closer inspection the Arch Wiki code suffers from incomplete uniqueness, in that only `dirstack` only when being written out is made unique, and not with `PWD`, nor when reading the file in. So if `PWD` contains something also in `dirstack`, duplicates will be created and then read in. Thus, the quickest fix is to apply the unique expansion on the read:

```
  dirstack=( ${(uf)"$(< $DIRSTACKFILE)"} )
```

And perhaps also to the file write, which is more complicated, as it needs a unique `dirstack` minus whatever is in `PWD` plus `PWD`.

```
print -l $PWD ${(u)${dirstack:#$PWD}} >$DIRSTACKFILE
```

Comment: Dammit, this slipped my mind. Nice idea, but for some reason, the top directory is still repeated when I start a new tab.